# How to cluster rows in dataset with two geospatial attributes

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, geospatial, unsupervised-learning

Title might be misleading as I wasn't sure how to properly summarize the problem.

I have a dataset of trips with two locations (source and destination) and also other attributes (about customer, cargo, equipment, etc).

Are there any algorithms that I could apply in order to cluster those trips, given that I want to use both spatial points (source and destination) for clustering, not just one.

Let's say if I have following trips:

```
A1 -> B1
A2 -> B2
A1 -> C1
A2 -> C2
```

I want to get clusters like:

```
A -> B
A -> C
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution I can think about is to cluster each location independently, and then use cluster ids to group by both clusters.

Something like (this was tested in Google BigQuery):

```
with data as (
  select st_geogpoint(100, 50) a, st_geogpoint(101, 51) b
  union all
  select st_geogpoint(100.01, 50) a, st_geogpoint(101.01, 51) b
  union all
  select st_geogpoint(100, 50.01) a, st_geogpoint(90, 51) b
  union all
  select st_geogpoint(100.01, 50.01) a, st_geogpoint(90, 51.01) b
),
clusters as (
  select 
      a, b, 
      st_clusterdbscan(a, 1e4, 1) OVER() a_id, 
      st_clusterdbscan(b, 1e4, 1) OVER() b_id
  from data
)
select 
    a_id, b_id, 
    st_centroid_agg(a) a_center, 
    st_centroid_agg(b) b_center
from clusters
group by a_id, b_id


a_id    b_id    a_center                        b_center
0       0       POINT(100.005 50.0000001074259) POINT(101.005 51.0000001066994)
0       1       POINT(100.005 50.0100001074192) POINT(90 51.005)
```

Comment: Thank you! 

I was mostly curious whether it would possible to apply some generally available clustering algorithms, such as DBSCAN (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) to my case where I want to cluster by two locations instead of one?